# Having issue with focus and blur function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Form where there are three field and two buttons. **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m6kujz51/)**

Clicking on **Add optional Email Address** button adds a new Email field which is fine. My issue is with **Save** Button. I am wanting the save button will remain disable until user click on the field or add any value in the input field. 
So,

- if a user click on any of the input field Save button will become
        active
- if a user put a value it will remain active.
- if user clicks on the input but didn't give any value it will Change
  to disable again.

Same for the New added input by **Add optional Email Address**

On my code it's not going back to disable state if no value given on the input after clicking and not working for newly added input. I am not sure the reason. Any help will save my day.

**JS**

```
$("body").on('focus', '.user-input input', function() {  
   $(".update-change").removeAttr('disabled');
}).blur(function() {
    if ($("").val() == '') {
        $(".update-change").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});

$('.update-list-confirm').click(function(){
    $(".update-change").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});


// Add email
$("body").on('click', '.add-new-email', function() {
    var newemail = '<div class="form-group"><em class="pull-right">Optional</em><input type="email" name="userEmail" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="mymail@mail.com"></div>';

$(newemail).insertBefore(this);     
});
```

Comment: Your requirements kind of clash "if a user click on any of the input field Save button will become active" and "if user clicks on the input but didn't give any value it will Change to disable again." Or do you mean for the last one if the user `blur` from the input it should go back to disabled?

Comment: I think b/c you have placeholder which .val() == '' will not work. didn't test it yet.

Comment: try `if ($(this).val() == '') {        $(".update-change").attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

Comment: You do realize that the *SAVE* button will be enabled even if three of the four input elements are left blank. You should combine the results of the four `.val()` tests before enabling the *SAVE*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to handle blur on the same input element

```
$("body").on('focus', '.user-input input', function() {  
   $(".update-change").removeAttr('disabled');
}).on ('blur', '.user-input input', function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
        $(".update-change").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: You should always use "===" when comparing to an empty value.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a typo? Change it with correct values:

```
if ($("").val() == '') {
```

I guess it should be:

```
if ($('[name="userEmail"]').val() == '') {
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable the SAVE button if ANY of the text fields are blank, you should use this snippet of code:

```
$(':text').focusout(function () {
    $(':text').each(function (i) {
        if (this.value === '') {
            $('.update-change').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

This way, when the SAVE button is clicked (and the `:text` fields are no longer in focus), each `:text` field is checked for a value.